# How to tell if the lowest point in the output of BoxPoints(rect) is the bottom right or bottom left point of the bounding box?

Tags: opencv

In answer to another question, [Sushanth stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58185432/11573842):

> The lowest point of the rectangle(does not matter left or right) will always be the first sub-list of the "box" ndarray. So in the example I have given, the first sub-list [169 144] represents the "bottom right of ***this*** rectangle".
> Now this point will be the reference point to decide what the next sub-list represents. Meaning, the next sub-list will always represent the point that you first get when you move in the **clockwise direction**. (as shown in the second image of the for loop)

I don't understand how to tell if the lowest point is the bottom-left or bottom-right point on the bases of the "first sub-list".

I need to create a generalized code that can tell them apart so that I can reliably apply `warpAffine` transformation to a dataset of images ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11627903/11573842)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739411/what-does-cv2-cv-boxpointsrect-return/58185432#comment113335930_58185432) is [Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11517841/sushanth)'s answer to my question:

> To determine whether it is a bottom-left or right in a scenario when
> the two bottom points have the same y-coordinate: i. First, have a
> conditional statement to see whether the two bottom points have the
> same y-coordinate. ii. If the condition is True, then check which
> coordinate has the **lowest x-value**(or the highest). The coordinate
> with the lowest x-value will be bottom-left of course! "How did you
> determine this just by looking at the sub-list?" -- I did not
> determine it by just looking at it! I could not! This is exactly why I
> wrote the above for-loop in my answer!

<sub>with minor spelling corrections from my side</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I learned later on that I actually didn't need that information for performing `warpAffine transformation` as the `angle` information is returned by `minAreaRect`

```py
def warp_contour(img,cnt):
    rows, cols = img.shape
    
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    center,_,angle = rect
    
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    
    rot = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1)
    img = cv2.warpAffine(img, rot, (rows,cols))
    
    return img
```

<sub>But I won't be accepting this answer as I still want to know how to tell them apart.</sub>